# How to extract words from string in ruby

Tags: ruby, substring

I want to extract words from string in ruby.

For example, I have a url string `"......../default/d1235sf3/......"`.

I want to extract `"d1235sf3"` from it. I am thinking using regex, but I don't know the grammar. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is a "word" to you? Do you also want to extract `"default"` here? What is the exact rule? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an excellent tutorial on regular expressions, and learning them will give you a lot of power - there won't always be someone to craft expressions for you. That said, you are welcome to post about *problems* you have with regular expressions *when you try something*.

Comment: I want to extract the string  "d1235sf3" in this case. it begins with "default/" and ends with "/". I don't want to extract "default".

Comment: What language does the word `d1235sf3` belong to, (and what does it mean)? It should not be English, because English does have the word `default`, but you have in mind a language that does not recognize that as a word.

Answer (score 2):

Use string.match with regex and isolate groups:

```
string = "http://test.com/something/default/d1235sf3/"
string.match("^.*\/default\/(.*)\/")
```

Notice how I structured my regex, isolating the part you are interested in with ().

NOTE: Regular expressions (regex) are a huge, marvelous and interesting subject which will help you in situations like this when you have to "match" text to a certain "mold", but I really can't go in depth here. This tutorial site seems pretty good, so you should get a refresher on how to use regex here: http://regexone.com/

`string.match` will produce a MatchData object with attributes corresponding to its matching groups:

```
=> #<MatchData "http://test.com/something/default/d1235sf3/" 1:"d1235sf3">
```

Notice how attribute 1 has the little bit of information that you want. Right after calling `string.match`, you can use the special variable `$1` in ruby to access the info that you want:

```
2.0.0-p643 :004 > $1
 => "d1235sf3" 
2.0.0-p643 :005 > info = $1
 => "d1235sf3" 
2.0.0-p643 :006 > info
 => "d1235sf3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "......../default/d1235sf3/......"
string[%r{/default/([^/]*)/}, 1]
# => "d1235sf3"
```

A short alternative to Alfredo's answer - this form of regexp (`string[regexp]` or `string[regexp, group]`) is well-suited to extracting a particular part of a string; using `%r{...}` instead of `/.../` is good to avoid having to escape slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
> string = "......../default/d1235sf3/......"
> string.split('/default/').last.split('/')[0]
#=> "d1235sf3"
```